# Identify rows based on a condition and select one above and one below

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

| ID | P | L | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |  |

I would like to select one row with L = 0 above and one row with L = 0 below the rows with L = 1, groupby ID and P. These rows are in red font in the image. If there are multiple rows with L = 1, the same rule applies (that is one row below and one row above). Any suggestion? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with actual value and chain mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` with `&` for bitwise `AND` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m11 = df['L'].eq(1)
m22 = df['L'].eq(0)

shifted1 = df.groupby(['ID','P'])['L'].shift(-1)
shifted2 = df.groupby(['ID','P'])['L'].shift()

m1 = m11 & shifted1.eq(0) 
m2 = m22 & shifted2.eq(1)

m3 = m22 & shifted1.eq(1) 
m4 = m11 & shifted2.eq(0)

out = df[(m1 | m2 | m3 | m4) & m22]
print (out)
    ID  P  L  Score
0    1  1  0    5.0
2    1  1  0    7.0
3    1  2  0   10.0
5    1  2  0    8.0
7    1  2  0    7.0
10   1  2  0    8.0
13   2  1  0   10.0
15   2  1  0    7.0
```

Another idea is replace `0` to missing values and use [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) with [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) and parameter `limit`:

```
g = df.assign(L = df['L'].mask(df['L'].eq(0))).groupby(['ID','P'])['L']
m22 = df['L'].eq(0)

out = df[(g.bfill(limit=1).eq(1) & m22) | (g.ffill(limit=1).eq(1) & m22) ]
print (out)
    ID  P  L  Score
0    1  1  0    5.0
2    1  1  0    7.0
3    1  2  0   10.0
5    1  2  0    8.0
7    1  2  0    7.0
10   1  2  0    8.0
13   2  1  0   10.0
15   2  1  0    7.0
```

Comment: Thank you but the results appear incorrect when having 3 consecutive rows with L = 1. I will need to check other cases before accepting your solution.

Comment: @Jason - Can you be more specific? `having 3 consecutive rows with L = 1`

Comment: It works fine. I just need to sort the data first. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple double [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['L'].eq(1)
g = m.groupby([df['ID'], df['P']])

m2 = (g.shift(fill_value=False) | g.shift(-1, fill_value=False))

out = df[m2&~m]
```

Output:

```
    ID  P  L  Score
0    1  1  0    5.0
2    1  1  0    7.0
3    1  2  0   10.0
5    1  2  0    8.0
7    1  2  0    7.0
10   1  2  0    8.0
13   2  1  0   10.0
15   2  1  0    7.0
```

Intermediates:

```
    ID  P  L  Score      m  shift  shift(-1)     m2  m2&~m
0    1  1  0    5.0  False  False       True   True   True
1    1  1  1    NaN   True  False      False  False  False
2    1  1  0    7.0  False   True      False   True   True
3    1  2  0   10.0  False  False       True   True   True
4    1  2  1    NaN   True  False      False  False  False
5    1  2  0    8.0  False   True       True   True   True
6    1  2  1    5.0   True  False      False  False  False
7    1  2  0    7.0  False   True       True   True   True
8    1  2  1    NaN   True  False       True   True  False
9    1  2  1    NaN   True   True      False   True  False
10   1  2  0    8.0  False   True      False   True   True
11   2  1  0    9.0  False  False      False  False  False
12   2  1  0    9.0  False  False      False  False  False
13   2  1  0   10.0  False  False       True   True   True
14   2  1  1    NaN   True  False      False  False  False
15   2  1  0    7.0  False   True       True   True   True
16   2  1  1    NaN   True  False      False  False  False
```

Comment: I think your codes are cleaner so +1 as well.